# Erro Json Line 0 position 0

Tags: c#, json

Já procurei aqui no site sobre esse erro e até agora não encontrei algo que resolva o meu problema.
Estou tentando utilizar restsharp, mas estou obtendo um erro na hora de passar os dados para .json

Minha Pagina com a API

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once("config/config.php");

$result = array('status' => 500, 'message' => "Internal error");

if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password']))
    {
  $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $uuid = 'Not Found';
  
  if (validaUsuario($login, $password) == true) 
  {
            $result['status'] ='42';
            $result['message'] = 'Connected with success';
   $result['user'] = 'Teste';
            $result['level'] = '100';   

   echo json_encode($result);
            return;
   
        } else 
  {
   $result['status'] =202;
            $result['message'] = "Password or login incorrect";
   $result['token'] = 123456789;
            $result['level'] = 10;
   echo json_encode($result);
            return;
  }
            
   echo json_encode($result);

 }

?>
```

Meu codigo:

```
public static void UserLogin(string user,string pass)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/r_user.php");

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.POST;

        request.AddParameter("login", user);
        request.AddParameter("password", pass);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;

        dynamic res = JObject.Parse(content);

        if (res.status == "42")
        {

        }
    }
```

Me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ﻿. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
```

Eu estou recebendo o content assim : `﻿﻿{"status":"42","message":"Connected with success","user":"Teste","level":"100"}`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: $result =(object) ['status' => 500, 'message' => 'Internal error'];
ja  tentou usar assim?

Comment: Tentei mas também não deu certo @Will

Comment: qual é o erro? seu método o C# espera `user` e `pass` porém você posta `login` e `password`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Obridado pela ajuda,consegui resolver, postei a resolução do problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de diversos teste, acabei descobrindo que era um problema fácil de se resolver.

Eu estava recebendo os dados visualmente corretos, copiei o retorno em json que eu estava recebendo e coloquei em [json validador](https://jsonlint.com/)

Nesse validador eu percebi que tinha um espaço antes da primeira chave, pra deserializar não pode ter um espaço na frente.
Eu estava utilizando o notepad++ e mudei a codificação pra UTF8-Sem BOM, mas o problema permaneceu, estudando mais percebi que todos os arquivos que o meu arquivo.php usa precisa está com a mesma codificação.

No meu caso eu chamava um outro arquivo:

```
require_once("config/config.php");
```

Alterei a condificação do config.php e o problema resolveu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]